# Javascript - Pass anonymous functions to Promise.all

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, axios, es6-promise

I'm trying to make multiple API calls concurrently using the Promise.all method with Axios, based on this example:

```
getUsers() { 
    return axios.get('/users');
}

getSessions() { 
    return axios.get('/sessions');
}

Promise.all([getUsers(), getSessions()])
    .then(results => {
      // Use the data
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Catch the error
    });
```

However, as I will only know what concurrent API calls I need to make at this stage based on the result of a previous API call in the promise chain, I'm attempting to pass in an array of anonymous functions to the function in the form of:

```
var array = [];
array.push(() => {return axios.get('/users')}); 
array.push(() => {return axios.get('/sessions')});

Promise.all(array).then....
```

This doesn't work, and I understand that this is because I'm passing in function objects instead of referencing actual Promise objects as the method expects. However, pushing just axios.get(...) methods to the array results in them being called immediately, instead of later when the Promise.all method is executed.

I'm not sure how to do this properly, or whether there's a better approach to achieve what I'm after...

Comment: What do you mean by "*results in them being called immediately, instead of later when the Promise.all method is executed.*"? In your example you are filling the `array` immediately before calling `Promise.all` anyway. You might want to post your actual code where you decide "*what concurrent API calls I need to make at this stage based on the result of a previous API call in the promise chain*".

Comment: I agree with Bergi. Your question doesn't make much sense. The entire point of `Promise.all` is to wait for a collection of Promises to resolve. If you don't have those Promises yet then there is no point on using `Promise.all` for anything, and you don't have those Promises until `axios.get(x)` has been called, so it seems like calling those functions immediately is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Paulpro @Bergi sorry if it wasn't clear - by _"results in them being called immediately, instead of later when the Promise.all method is executed."_, what I meant was if I did something like `array.push(axios.get('/users'))` then the axios.get() method would be executed immediately as part of the push to the array, instead of being executed later when I invoked the Promise.all() method with the total array contents..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not familiar with Axios, but if I understand correctly `axios.get` returns a `Promise`, which you need for `Promise.all`. How about:

```
Promise.all(array.map(f => f()).then....
```

That way your functions are called when you actually want, and the `map` will give you an array of their results, so an array of `Promise`s.

Note that this is essentially the same as the example you have cited with `[getUsers(), getSessions()]` – with the difference that your functions are anonymous and called implicitly using the `map`, instead of explicitly by their names. This way you have more flexibility in which functions actually get called.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, in siplest scenario, **to use anonymous function** as a wrapper, you need to **call it before** you are put it to Promise.all.

So just try to :

```
const f = async () => {return service.myFunc();}

Promise.all([f()])
```

so, your wrapper (f) calling before, and you are providing array with one Promise.

or

```
Promise.all([(async () => {const result = await service.myFunc(); return result;})()]);
```

or (equal) :

```
const myPromise = (async () => {const result = await service.myFunc(); return result;})();

Promise.all([myPromise]);
```

So Promise will be provided to Promise.all, not just raw function. Also, be carefully and do not forget to use `await` in case of "big anonym function body".

Answer (score 0):

i've been scratching my head about this for the longest time. in the first example you call the functions here:

> Promise.all([getUsers(), getSessions()])

but in the second the anonymous functions are just stated, never called:

> array.push( ()=>{return axios.get('/users')} );

so you would need to do this and call them as you pushed them:

> array.push( (()=>{return axios.get('/users')}) () );

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and found out that you can do it with [p-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-all):

```js
import pAll from 'p-all'

await pAll([() => { /* ... */ }, () => { /* ... */ }])
```